# pysaml2 not working after implementing websockets

Tags: python, flask, websocket, socket.io, single-sign-on

I'm using Flask to create a web application, I first started by implementing SSO, I used pysaml2 to connect to AWS which would in turn return my user information and login the user.

SSO was working perfectly fine until I implemented socketio (websockets) into the application to handle real time push notifications and then I started getting this from AWS when trying to login with SSO:

```
Something went wrong.
We could not sign you in to your service provider


Oops, something went wrong
Provide your administrator with the following info:
No access
```

I re-published my main branch that doesn't include any websockets and SSO login worked perfectly fine. Does anyone know what the issue could be?

The following is my code for SSO:

```
from saml2 import (
    BINDING_HTTP_POST,
    BINDING_HTTP_REDIRECT
)
from saml2.client import Saml2Client
from saml2.config import Config as Saml2Config
from flask import abort, Blueprint, current_app, session

@app.route("/user")
def user():
    return render_template('user.html')

def saml_client_for(idp_name):
    """
    Given the name of an IdP, return a configuation.
    The configuration is a hash for use by saml2.config.Config
    """

    if idp_name not in current_app.config['SAML_IDP_SETTINGS']:
        raise Exception(f'Settings for IDP "{idp_name}" not found on SAML_IDP_SETTINGS.')
    
    acs_url = url_for(
        'saml_login',
        _external=True)
    
    https_acs_url = url_for(
        'saml_login',
        _external=True,
        _scheme='https')

    # SAML metadata changes very rarely. On a production system,
    # this data should be cached as approprate for your production system.
    rv = requests.get(current_app.config['SAML_IDP_SETTINGS'][idp_name]['metadata_url'])

    entityid = current_app.config['SAML_IDP_SETTINGS'][idp_name].get('entityid', acs_url)

    settings = {
        'entityid': entityid,
        'metadata': {
            'inline': [rv.text],
        },
        'service': {
            'sp': {
                'endpoints': {
                    'assertion_consumer_service': [
                        (acs_url, BINDING_HTTP_REDIRECT),
                        (acs_url, BINDING_HTTP_POST),
                        (https_acs_url, BINDING_HTTP_REDIRECT),
                        (https_acs_url, BINDING_HTTP_POST)
                    ],
                },
                # Don't verify that the incoming requests originate from us via
                # the built-in cache for authn request ids in pysaml2
                'allow_unsolicited': True,
                # Don't sign authn requests, since signed requests only make
                # sense in a situation where you control both the SP and IdP
                'authn_requests_signed': False,
                'logout_requests_signed': True,
                'want_assertions_signed': False,
                'want_response_signed': False
            }
        }
    }

    current_app.logger.info('settings: %s', settings)

    saml2_config = Saml2Config()
    saml2_config.load(settings)
    saml2_config.allow_unknown_attributes = True
    
    saml2_client = Saml2Client(config=saml2_config)
    
    return saml2_client


@app.route("/loginSSO/", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def saml_login():
    idp_name = "..."
    if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            saml_client = saml_client_for(idp_name)

            current_app.logger.debug('request.form: %s', request.form)

            authn_response = saml_client.parse_authn_request_response(
                request.form['SAMLResponse'],
                BINDING_HTTP_POST
            )

            current_app.logger.info('authn_response: %s', authn_response)

            authn_response.get_identity()
            subject = authn_response.get_subject()
            current_app.logger.info('subject: %s', subject)
            user_id = subject.text
            name = authn_response.ava['name'][0]
            email = authn_response.ava['email'][0]
            groups = authn_response.ava['Groups']
            groups_string = ', '.join(groups)
            
            user = UserSSO.query.filter_by(email=email).first()

            if not user:
                user = UserSSO(name=name, email=email, role=groups_string)
                db.session.add(user)
                db.session.commit()
                session["user_login_method"] = "SSO"
                login_user(user)
            else:
                session["user_login_method"] = "SSO"
                login_user(user)
            # This is what as known as "Just In Time (JIT) provisioning".
            # What that means is that, if a user in a SAML assertion
            # isn't in the user store, we create that user first, then log them in

            
            session['saml_attributes'] = authn_response.ava

            redirect_url = url_for('index')

            if request.form.get('RelayState'):
                redirect_url = request.form['RelayState']

            return redirect(redirect_url)
        except Exception as e:
            current_app.logger.exception('Exception raised during SAML SSO login')
            flash(e)
            return redirect_url("index")
    else:
        try:
            saml_client = saml_client_for(idp_name)
            reqid, info = saml_client.prepare_for_authenticate()

            current_app.logger.info('reqid: %s', reqid)
            current_app.logger.info('info: %s', info)

            redirect_url = None

            # Select the IdP URL to send the AuthN request to
            _, redirect_url = next(filter(lambda k_v: k_v[0] == 'Location', info['headers']))

            current_app.logger.info('redirect_url: %s', redirect_url)
            
            response = redirect(redirect_url, code=302)
            
            response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache, no-store'
            response.headers['Pragma'] = 'no-cache'
            
            return response
        except Exception as e:
            current_app.logger.exception('Exception raised during SAML SSO login')
            flash(e)
            return redirect_url("index")
```

The following is how I'm running my application and websocket:

```
socketio = SocketIO(app,logger=True, engineio_logger=True, async_mode="gevent")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

If anyone knows what could be causing this issue please let me know since I've been stuck for hours trying to figure it out